# Keylogger for non jailbroken iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to record user keystrokes in the virtual keyboard of an iphone? (Like a spy/malware application?)

I know that other applications cannot run in background for indefinite time, but they can run for a finite period like 10 minutes. Question is that can, within this time frame, they listen to keyboard notifications and capture user's input?

Comment: Erm, can you explain why you want this?  Also, what have you tried so far?  Any source code you can provide to show your efforts so far?

Comment: @griegs We have a secure application which is accessed by a pin/password. Customer wanted to know if there could be a way with which someone can create a snooper application which can read out your password as you type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Code would be

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(textFieldDidChange:) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

but that only works within your program. NSDistributedNotificationCenter is not available in iOS, and even then, it wouldn't be active by default.

Also, Apple would prevent any means of keylogging on a technical level to start with.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to record user keystrokes in the virtual keyboard of an iphone?

Yes, since the device allows the [malicious] program to access the accelerometer (which does *not* have a permission). See [TapLogger: Inferring User Inputs On Smartphone Touchscreens Using On-board Motion Sensors](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~szhu/papers/taplogger.pdf).

Comment: Hi jww, thanks for sharing this research article it definitely sounds convincing and possible to use various sensors for keylogging. Since the announce of custom keyboard in iOS, it seems entirely possible to just create a custom keyboard which can do this for you, far more easily I guess.